# MERN - can't write to connected mongoose database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, npm, mongoose

I am creating a full-stack MERN application, and I am having trouble writing to the database. I have made a connection, and making GET requests to the database works.

Connection string:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rapidosPortal',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
)

module.exports = mongoose.connection
```

The server connected:
[Server Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI7Nk.png)

server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
const db = require('./config/connection')
const routes = require('./routes')

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')))
}

app.use(routes)

db.once('open', () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Now listening on localhost: ${PORT}`))
})
```

Network Request:
[API Request In Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnzx7.png)

Here is my controller, it makes it all the way to `Employee.create()`, but never past that, unless it errors out.

```
async function createEmployee(req, res) {
  try {
    const missingParams = await findMissingParams(
      ['employee_name', 'email', 'password'],
      req.body
    )
    if (missingParams)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: `Missing Parameters: ${missingParams.join(', ')}` })

    const alreadyOne = await validateEmployee(req.body)
    if (alreadyOne)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Employee already exists!' })

    console.log('!! request body', req.body)
    const employee = await Employee.create(req.body)
    console.log('!! create employee', employee)

    const token = signToken(employee)

    return res.status(200).json({ employee, token })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json(err)
  }
}
```

Then it hangs there not completing, as you can see by the next log not getting outputted to the console.

Server Console:
[Console Not FInishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc9wL.png)

I've tried re-cloning the repo but that didn't do anything. I also went to my window services and restarted the mongodb server.

I have a seed file that creates the employees just fine and doesn't hang.

Seed file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const Employee = require('../../models/Employee')
const Profile = require('../../models/Profile')
const employees = require('./employees.json')
const profiles = require('./profiles.json')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

async function seedDatabase() {
  await Profile.deleteMany({})
  const newProfiles = await Profile.insertMany(profiles)

  await Employee.deleteMany({})
  const newEmployees = employees.map((emp, index) => ({
    ...emp,
    profile: newProfiles[index]._id,
  }))
  console.log('!! new employees: ', newEmployees)
  await Employee.insertMany(newEmployees)
}

mongoose
  .connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rapidosPortal',
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => seedDatabase())
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    mongoose.connection.close()
  })
  .finally(() => mongoose.connection.close())
```

These created employees are also in my local database.

MongoDB Compass:
[MongoDB Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA5cZ.png)

This repository does work on Heroku, I believe it is a problem with my local database

Sorry if this isn't done properly, first post on here!

Thanks for any help